# Loading multiple reportviewers in parallel

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

We have a requirement to show 3 graphs in SSRS report format.
So, we have developed an ASP.NET (F/W 4.0) web page with 3 report viewer (Version:10) controls placed on the web page (hosted under IIS 7.0).
Each report viewer control will be loaded with the respective SSRS report (.rdl) from the SSRS server in REMOTE mode (with AsyncRenedering = True which is default).

When we run the page, we expected that 3 reports will get loaded concurrently (or) in parallel.

But in reality, the reportviewer controls are loading the reports sequentially in the order their placement on the web page.

I tried to move the report population logic into a ThreadStart but that did not help - getting an error

> Object reference not set to instance of an object

when I access reportviewer control in the thread.

Please let me know if there is a way to have the reportviewer control load the reports in parallel & not in sequence (without using IFRAMEs).

Thanks & Regards

Praveen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems known issue with ReportViewerControl. 
Please go through link below for more information.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8fc7b09-ae3b-4a4c-822b-fede10685436/multiple-report-viewers-on-one-page-issue?forum=sqlreportingservices

Adding summery from above link

This is a known limitation with the current version of the report viewer and something we would like to address in the future.  I have seen customers work around this problem by placing the report viewers on their own page and using an iframe on your main page.  The browser should then render them in parallel if they are using server mode and you don’t use ASP.Net session.  In local mode or in server mode with ASP.Net session, ASP.Net will serialize the requests by locking on the session.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add a summary of what's on the page at that link in case the link ever goes down?